# jQuery UI Multiselect widget clear all check boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hopefully a quick one...

I need to fire the uncheckAll event in the click event of a separate button on my page, I have tried the following:

```
$('.masterProviderOrgsListBox').multiselect().uncheckAll();
```

but this isnt a recognised method. I basically want to fire the same method that is fired when you click the "Uncheck All" box in the header.

I was previously doing this:

```
$('.masterProviderOrgsListBox option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
```

but this removes the selections on the actual multiselect rather than the jQuery UI widget.

Couldnt find anything in the documentation, any ideas?

Comment: Which plugin are you using? There is no jQuery UI Multiselect AFAIK.

Comment: It's this one: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Comment: Can you use a javascript method to check all the members of your multiselect? and for each; if selected= true, then revert selection by setting selected=false

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **Methods**
>
> After an instance has been initialized, interact with it by calling
>   any of these methods:
>
> `// example: $("#multiselect").multiselect("method_name");`

...which can be found in the widgets [documentation](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) under **Methods**

```
$("#multiselect").multiselect("uncheckAll");
```

Comment: An example of calling **refresh()** method -  To clear the seach input field on opening the dropdown, put this inside `open` event handler -  `$(".ui-widget-header input[type=search]").val(""); $(this).multiselect("refresh");`

Answer (score 1):

1) first, you need to set default value of the control. 
 
`jQuery('#multiselect').val("");` 

2) Then, execute below code to reset the control. 
 
`jQuery('#multiselect').multiselect("refresh");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#multiselectoption:selected").removeAttr("selected");
$("#multiselect").multiselect('refresh');
```

refresh should be call after clearing the drop down.